# C# WPF - Formatting a datagrid after importing from csv

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, string-formatting, import-csv

I have imported a csv datatable and all columns are formatted as strings. Is there a way to change the format column values to short date or currency after it has been imported?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you do, what exactly do you want to happen.  Include an explanation of everything relevant so people do not waste time with suggestions to find you then didn't mention something means that ain't going to work. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you saying that all the columns in the `DataTable` are of type string? You don't have any `DateTime` or `Decimal` columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `StringFormat`

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="MyData" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,2,3,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=M/d/yyyy}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Price, StringFormat=C}"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

You can check out the string format class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2